# What is the name of a movie on [adult swim] where children run around an empty Tokyo-esque city?

Tags: anime, identify-this-movie

I remember watching a Japanese anime movie on [adult swim] years ago about a group of children wandering around a city that resembles Tokyo, with [lion statues](http://image.yaymicro.com/rz_1210x1210/0/26e/japanese-lion-statue-26eec5.jpg) and [torii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torii). I've looked through [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Adult_Swim) but none of the movies listed match what I remember. For a long time, I thought the name of the movie was [Battle Royale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Royale_%28film%29), but I later learned this was false. I think the reason I believed the name was Battle Royale was because it seemed like a version of [The Warriors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warriors_%28film%29) with children.

I believe that I saw  this movie sometime between 2005 and 2008. Other than the possible plot of the children being sent out into an empty city, I don't remember much more of the plot. My most vivid memory of the movie is two children under a lion statue with a torii in the background.

Most of the movie was red. It seemed like most of the buildings and objects except for the children were red.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the story? And giving us a time frame to work with would also be good. In fact, any little detail you can add would help.

Comment: I added what more details I could.

Comment: This sounds a bit like [Tekkonkinkreet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FfXWg7_AGI).

Comment: It has very similar art style! I remember the art style being somewhere between Spirited Away and that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The movie, if I'm not mistaken, was a Halloween special that aired once and then never again called [Kakurenbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakurenbo) aka Kakurenbo: Hide & Seek.

> A young boy named Hikora enters the ruins of a forbidden city with a
>   group of other children to play "Otokoyo" (a game of hide-and-seek
>   where the players are said to be kidnapped by ghosts and demons) to
>   find his missing sister. - [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0489102/)

[image]

Comment: That moment when this user is actually right! I'm 95% certain that this is the answer to my question. I'll be watching Kakurenbo over the weekend to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

As you've also tagged this as [identify-this-tv-show](/questions/tagged/identify-this-tv-show), I'd like to suggest that you might have watched an episode of [Dennou Coil (aka Cyber Coil)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denn%C5%8D_Coil). It is from 2007 and features children running around in a virtual world. I can distinctly remember a scene in a temple with a *torii*.

> a Japanese science fiction anime television series depicting a near future where semi-immersive augmented reality (AR) technology has just begun to enter the mainstream. The series takes place in the fictional city of Daikoku, a hotbed of AR development with an emerging city-wide virtual infrastructure. It follows a group of children as they use AR glasses to unravel the mysteries of the half real, half Internet city, using a variety of illegal software tools, techniques, and virtual pets to manipulate the digital landscape.

I'm not sure about the red tint. But the animation does sometimes carry an other-worldly feel to it. Here's some artwork:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like Fractale. I'll look into this when I have a chance.